The meaning of sentences and time
Does adding  time to sentences change their meaning? For instance

When I cook she visits me.

When I cook in 4 mintues she visits me.


A)  1 shows that she arrives during my cooking. I know that 2 isn't really likely becuase on average cooking takes longer but it is just an example and let's say I prepare something really easy that takes only 3 to 4 mintues. Does adding time changes the meaning of my 2 sentence that is she arrives after cooking or it still has the same meaning that her arrivng occurs while I am in the middle of cooking?

When she pinches me I laugh

When she pinches me for 10 minutes I laugh


B) Again 3 shows first "pich" next action "laughing". Doesn't adding time change the meaning to during pinching I laugh not after?
The purpose of this question is to check if adding time changes the meaning. Those examples which I presented will make it easier for me to understand your response. Thanks in advance.

3 and 4 are OK because getting pinched causes you to laugh. It's not clear what 1 and 2 are supposed to mean - every time you cook, or on one particular occasion? And what do you mean by "visit" - it can mean simply arrive but more usually it means come in, have a chat, catch up, drink tea or eat a meal? If you mean that you were cooking a short meal and she arrived during that time, you would more likely say something like "While I was cooking a four-minute meal, she arrived". It's not natural to add a time phrase as in 2, but 1 isn't very natural either.

@StuartF compare "when I eat she  will arrive" to me it implies during eating. "When I eat in two minutes, she will arrive"  first exsmple implies during eating  because it is a time consuming activity on the other hand second version where I state that it only takes to minutes to finish esting may imply that she arrives after eating not during?

In your language, does "When I cook in 4 mintues she visits me." make sense? I doubt it. So, why would it make sense in English? How is this really even a question about English??

I assume you mean minutes, but what is (2) supposed to mean? Every time I start to cook something, she knocks on the door four minutes later?

Two points:  Weird and artificial sentences have weird meanings.  Often if you actually use such weird expressions, people will assume you made a mistake and try to guess your meaning to be different. Secondly  of course if you change or add words to a sentence you change the meaning.  It is very rare that you can change a sentence and not change the meaning too.

You can make minor changes to your question (e.g. grammar fixes) after people have answered, but you can't completely rewrite it.

1. When I turn off the Tv she arrives
2. When I sleep she arries When I do my homework, she arrives
3. When I do my homework in just 5 minutes, she arrives. Can these happen repeatedly?

The distinction you make between "long" and "short" activities is specious. The distinction is between actions that have completed (and the verb phrase expresses a sense of completion) and actions that are ongoing (and the verb phrase does not express any sense of completion).
Here are two completed actions, one long, one short:

When I have served my 30-year prison sentence, she arrives to pick me up at the prison door.
When I've zapped the egg for a mere three seconds in this fancy new powerful microwave oven, it begins to change texture.

Here are three  sentences, one that works and two that don't:

When I have zapped the egg for three seconds, I take it out of the microwave oven.
When I  zap the egg for three seconds she knocks on the door.
When I zap the egg for an hour she knocks on the door.


OP's four sentences are:


When I cook she visits me.
When I cook in 4 mintues she visits me.
When she pinches me I laugh.
When she pinches me for 10 minutes I laugh.


Remember the rule when simple present is used:
We use the simple present tense when an action is happening right now, or when it happens regularly.
(You can also use it when you are narrating a story for dramatic effect).
So your first and second sentences seems unlikely to happen repeatedly.(these sentences imply unlikely correlations. Only sentence 3 is possible.).

The purpose of this question is to check if adding time changes the meaning.

You have a valid point
Alternatively consider these sentences and the explanation how adding time indicator affects the sentence
1a) When she nags me I lose my temper.
1 b) When she nags me for 15 minutes, I lose my temper.
(1a can mean you get angry immediately when she starts nagging.
1b) Specifies your tolerance limit (15 mins)
2a) When I listen to a sermon I fall asleep.
2b) When I listen to a sermon for an hour I fall asleep.
(2b indicates when an action occurs  (after an hour).
3a) When my laptop is on, the battery gets healed.
3b) When my laptop is on for 30 mins, the battery gets healed.
(3b) Shows duration leading to a consequence

Setting aside narrative fiction, all of your examples would refer to habitual or regular or typical actions, whereas OP's examples refer to discrete one-time events. You realize this, of course, and point out how the present can be used for regular events.  So you shouldn't be telling OP that they have "a valid point".  The question is reasonable, but OP's central point is misguided.  It has nothing to do with how long the action takes.

@TimR I wished to show OP how his sentences were wrong. But after seeing the edited sentence I think OP didn't understand.

In all these examples, the sentence could be interpreted to mean "during" or "after". Adding a time period doesn't really change that, except that we would probably understand it to mean that the event doesn't happen until the time period has elapsed. Like to take you last example, "When she pinches me for ten minutes ..." If she's been pinching you for 5 minutes, than we probably don't know whether she will continue another 5 minutes to make it 10, or if she will now stop. So, barring other information from the context, I'd assume that you don't start laughing until 10 minutes have passed.
